# Android VideoView: video goes black after being removed from parent view

Tags: android, video-streaming, fullscreen, android-videoview

I am currently playing an rtsp live streaming source using a VideoView. This works fine.

The VideoView is initially inside a fragment with other elements, in 'normal' state, and I am trying to implement a fullscreen toggle button.

To go to fullscreen mode, I am removing the VideoView from its parent (a LinearLayout), and then adding it to another LinearLayout, added on top of everything else using getActivity().addContentView(), here's the code:

```
    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();          
    vFullScreen = lf.inflate(R.layout.full_screen, myViewGroup, false);             

    LinearLayout fullscreenCont = (LinearLayout) vFullScreen.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_container);

    ((ViewGroup) vsPlayer.getParent()).removeView(vsPlayer);

    fullscreenCont.addView(vsPlayer);

    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    getActivity().addContentView(vFullScreen, params);
```

The problem is that the video goes black once it's removed from the original parent view.

What I'm trying to achieve it's to preserve the video instance to avoid having to reconnect/buffer again, but I don't know how to preserve the video playback during this switching of parents, any ideas?

EDIT:

If I suspend the videoView and then resume it, like this:

```
LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();          
vFullScreen = lf.inflate(R.layout.full_screen, myViewGroup, false);             

LinearLayout fullscreenCont = (LinearLayout) vFullScreen.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_container);

vsPlayer.getVideoView().suspend();
((ViewGroup) vsPlayer.getParent()).removeView(vsPlayer);

fullscreenCont.addView(vsPlayer);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
getActivity().addContentView(vFullScreen, params);
vsPlayer.getVideoView().resume();
```

the video play is interrupted (goes black for a few noticeable seconds) but then resumes, wich is a lot better, not perfect because it takes too long to resume play.

Another not so good part is that the methods suspend() and resume() of the class VideoView are available from API level 8 and up, and I need to be compatible with API level 7

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that the VideoView you're using goes black and temporarily lingers in between the switching of the views?

If so, I've been trying to figure out the cause of that issue for a solid week now. I haven't been able to figure out the actual cause, but my workaround does prevent the VideoView from persisting through screen changes:

```
public void hideVideoView(){        
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            findViewById(R.id.yourVideoView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });    
}
```

I'm basically just setting the view to invisible whenever the view gets switched, and if the view is reloaded I just set it back to View.Visible

Comment: unless I call suspend() on the VideoView before removing it from its parent, and then calling resume after adding it to the new parent view, the video goes black and never resumes. With these calls, the video resumes after a noticeable pause, and according to the logs, MediaPlayer seems to be released completely and restarted, that must be the reason why it taks so long to resume/come back from black

Comment: I still get a black screen.
I've asked a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903232/android-video-view-creates-a-black-screen-after-the-video

Answer (score 0):

This probably won´t :) resolve your problem, but you could seek to the position you where at before removing the VideoView:

```
long progress = vsPlayer.getCurrentPosition(); 


LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();          
vFullScreen = lf.inflate(R.layout.full_screen, myViewGroup, false);             

LinearLayout fullscreenCont = (LinearLayout)    vFullScreen.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_container);

((ViewGroup) vsPlayer.getParent()).removeView(vsPlayer);

fullscreenCont.addView(vsPlayer);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
getActivity().addContentView(vFullScreen, params);

vsPlayer.seekTo(progress);
```

I actually had the same issue some time ago.. What i ended up doing was to change the layoutparams of the VideoView to match_parent instead of removing it.

```
mVideoView.getLayoutParams().width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
mVideoView.getLayoutParams().height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
Seeking wouldn't be necessary, because I am playing a live stream, there's no problem there.
For the second part, I understand what you suggest, I will try to do this, the thing is my videoview is inside a fragment, that is itself inside a tab, so I don't know if I can make it 'grow' fullscreen from where it is, it definitely needs to be bigger that it's parent, so LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT is not goind to make it in this case... will try to find some alternative