# Android video view creates a black screen after the video

Tags: android, android-webview, android-videoview

I'm using Android's VideoView for playing locally stored mp4 videos. My app is a hybrid app, i.e. a webview based app, and i'm using native code to play videos. The video plays in the same activity as that of the webview. I'm facing an issue only with Android version 4.0.X.
Before starting the video i toggle the visibility of webview and videoview so that webview is invisible and videoview is visible. After the video is over, i reverse this. I still see a black screen over the webview whose area is the same as the video dimensions. For example, if video is covering only partial screen and plays in the center of the screen, then only that much area remains black. And this gets removed only if i change the orientation of the app. Both the webview and videoview are under a Frame Layout.
Why does this happen, and only in Android 4.0.X? Pls help.